# Affect overlapping elements when div is hovered the animation is reversed

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm having issues with the "Følg Oss" hover animation being reversed when the facebook, snapchat and instagram icons are hovered over. **I do not want this to happen.** I just want it to normally glide back when you're not hovering the .følg

Another problem is I'm not able to make the icons into links as the animation does not work if I add the href in the html as you are supposed to on images

I'm really really in the world of codin, so I apologize if I'm not good enough at formulating my problem...

```css
body {
    background-color: Black;
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-attatchment: fixed;
 background-position: center top;
 background-size: 100%
 width: 100%;
}
.følg {
    position: absolute; top: 90%; left: 25% ; z-index: 1507;
    width: 50%;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
.følg:hover{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -20.3vh, 0vh);
}
.følg:hover ~.fb{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -23.3vh, 0vh);
}
.følg:hover ~.insta{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -23.3vh, 0vh);
}
.følg:hover ~.snap{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -23.3vh, 0vh);
}
.faq {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: -1%; left: 13% ; z-index: 3;
    width: 24%;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.kjøp {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: -1%; left: 37% ; z-index: 4;
    width: 24%;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.news {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: -1%; left: 61% ; z-index: 2;
    width: 24%;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.news:hover, .kjøp:hover, .faq:hover{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, 3vh, 0vh);
}
.baeA {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 59% ; z-index: 1505;
    width: 4%;
}
.baeB {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 35% ; z-index: 1504;
    width: 4%;
}
.baeC {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 83% ; z-index: 1503;
    width: 3%;
}
.baeD {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 12% ; z-index: 1502;
    width: 3%;
}
.fb {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 38% ; z-index: 1509;
    width: 6%;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
.insta {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 46.5% ; z-index: 1509;
    width: 6%;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
.snap {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 55% ; z-index: 1509;
    width: 6%;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }
  
    function initialiseAxisImages() {
        var axis = document.getElementById('axis');
        var axisImages = axis.getElementsByTagName('News');

        axisImages[0].classList.remove('News');
        axisImages[1].classList.remove('move-left');
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', initialiseAxisImages, false);
    </style>
</head>
<body style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nFv2eoG.png" class="news" alt="Lime"  /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/n5eovvX.png" class="faq" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b7iknCb.png" class="kjøp" alt="Lime" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yJqMvpT.png" class="følg" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeA" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeB" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeC" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeD" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Tp9TaNM.png" class="fb" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXR7rmq.png" class="insta" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/STWEZOp.png" class="snap" alt="Lime" />
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do full-screen or everything will get jumbled which I also don't know how to fix ~sigh

Comment: The problem then is that the icons are not contained inside the `.følg` element. it would  be better to make `.følg` a `div` with a backgrounde image then add the icons inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body style="overflow:hidden">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nFv2eoG.png" class="news" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/n5eovvX.png" class="faq" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b7iknCb.png" class="kjøp" alt="Lime" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yJqMvpT.png" class="følg" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeA" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeB" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeC" alt="Lime" /> 
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QPQSByR.png" class="baeD" alt="Lime" /> 
    <span id="fblink"><a id="" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Tp9TaNM.png" class="fb" alt="Lime" /> </a></span>
    <a id="instalink" href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXR7rmq.png" class="insta" alt="Lime" /> </a>
    <a id="snaplink" href="https://www.snapchat.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/STWEZOp.png" class="snap" alt="Lime" /></a>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
          </div>

          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
          </div>

          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
          </div>

          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WioHdhd.png" alt="Sko" >
          </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

The css:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    background-color: Black;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attatchment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100%
    width: 100%;
}
.følg {
    position: absolute; top: 90%; left: 25% ; z-index: 1507;
    width: 50%;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
.følg:hover{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -20.3vh, 0vh);
}
.følg:hover ~#fblink{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -23.3vh, 0vh);
}
.følg:hover ~.insta{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -23.3vh, 0vh);
}
.følg:hover ~.snap{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, -23.3vh, 0vh);
}
.faq {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: -1%; left: 13% ; z-index: 3;
    width: 24%;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.kjøp {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: -1%; left: 37% ; z-index: 4;
    width: 24%;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.news {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: -1%; left: 61% ; z-index: 2;
    width: 24%;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
.news:hover, .kjøp:hover, .faq:hover{
    transform: translate3d(0vh, 3vh, 0vh);
}
.baeA {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 59% ; z-index: 1505;
    width: 4%;
}
.baeB {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 35% ; z-index: 1504;
    width: 4%;
}
.baeC {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 83% ; z-index: 1503;
    width: 3%;
}
.baeD {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 12% ; z-index: 1502;
    width: 3%;
}
img .fb {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 38% ; z-index: 1509;
    width: 6%;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
#instalink {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 46.5% ; z-index: 1509;
    width: 6%;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
#snaplink {
    image-attatchment: fixed;
    position: absolute; top: 110%; left: 55% ; z-index: 1509;
    width: 6%;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}

.fb {
    width: 50px;
    height 50px;
}
```

You are still going to need to do some editing. Firstly, the images are not going to suffice as the lower drawer. You are going to need to create a div for it and add the three images (fb, insta and snapchat) in it and apply transitions to the drawer as a whole and all the resulting links in it.

How to create links is shown in the code above. Although the formating and positioning of the image links is not the best, it should provide you some idea about how to go about it.

Hope it helps.